# Add multiple channels to a 28x28x5000 matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have an array of size 28x28x5000. I need to convert it to 28x28x3x5000. The third dimension represents channels. Each channel is the same copy.

How can I do this in Matlab without using a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another one-liner is `repmat(reshape(A,[28,28,1,5000]),1,1,3,1);`

Comment: This is the worst of the solutions, as you need to explicitly write the dimensions. Still a good one :P ;)

Comment: @AnderBiguri You're right, it is ugly.  I just figured I'd answer a very specific question with a very specific answer and avoid extra overhead.  Your solution is certainly more elegant.

Answer (score 3):

What about `repmat(permute(A,[1,2,4,3]),[1,1,3,1])`

Answer (score 3):

First [**`permute`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) to get the 4th dimension, then copy with [**`repmat`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html):

```
%// input data
a  = magic(28);
in = repmat(a,[1,1,100]);

%// permute
out = permute(in,[1,2,4,3]);

%// copy
out(:,:,[2 3],:) = repmat( out(:,:,1,:), [1, 1, 2]);
```